# React Native - Make WebView on Android behave the same as on iPhone

Tags: android, react-native, android-webview, crosswalk

I've built a RN app that shows prices for a product and redirect the user to the web page in order to complete his order. On iPhone the web page looks the same inside the app as it looks while opened with Safari or Chrome, but on android I have some issues. When opening the web page from Chrome or the default browser, it looks great but inside the app when using WebView it looks a bit broken.

I've tried using many many external components, but none worked.
The best I could do was using react-native-webview-crosswalk which uses the crosswalk driver for the webview, but they have a known issue with the app crashing (not only in RN) when focusing on a text field input.

https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/si/jira.issueviews:issue-html/XWALK-6997/XWALK-6997.html

Tried with many devices. Besides that, the app looks great! But unless I have a fix for that, I can't use it.

So that's why I'm here. After many many hours spent on it and many different implementations, It seems like I'm entering a dead end. Unless one of you guys can help me or guide me to a better solution. I have some native Android knowledge so open to any idea.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the webview isn't up to date on your device

Comment: @LunarWatcher tried on many devices and also Genymotion emulators on my mac. Also, on my devices inside the developer tools I see "Chrome stable" as the default webview driver.